# How much bounty is out on Stackoverflow?

Tags: code-golf, internet

**Task:**

You are an amazing programmer and Stackoverflow-answerer, and you decide to answer every question with a bounty on Stackoverflow. You are so good, that you manage to get all the bounties in all the questions. While you wait for the rep to come flooding in, you write a program that goes and find out what the total amount of rep is in all those bounties.

**Rules:**

- When run,

  - Your program will navigate through the featured tab on Stack Overflow.
  - It will scrape out the value of each bounty,
  - Then it will add it up and display the total
- It has to download data from anywhere on SO (and only SO), but I would recommend using https://stackoverflow.com/questions?pagesize=50&sort=featured , as it is only about 10 pages
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins

Comment: *cough* https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/featured-questions *cough*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured. All featured questions on 1 page.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs that's not all of them. Scroll to the bottom. eg when I just loaded it, it was showing 96 of 472 questions.

Comment: [Bounty API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/featured-questions#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=!*NF50n5ILcgi-6Kp&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

Comment: @justhalf already been discussed...

Comment: I'm pointing to the exact URL which will produce bounty scores, not just the API page as pointed out by @bazzargh. =)

Comment: Currently: 36100 (just if somebody is interested and does not want to execute a script)#

Comment: @moose how'd you figure that out?

Comment: @TheDoctor: I've executed one of the Python scripts below.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### JavaScript - <del>176</del> <del>133</del> <del>130</del> <del>108</del> 106

```js
function f()(t+=$("[title~=an]").text(),u=$("[rel*=x]")[0])?$("html").load(u.href,f):alert(eval(t));f(t=0)
```

*Edit 1: trimmed some selectors down and used the `?:` suggestion from Google's Closure Compiler (via @Sirko - thanks)*

*Edit 2: initialise `s` inside `d` and initialise `t` as `0` instead of `""`*

*Edit 3: realised I don't actually need to target a specific container and can sweep the whole document, which gets rid of a bunch of `.find` calls and an unnecessary selector (plus the variable holding it)*

*Edit 4: shove the `t` initialiser in the function call to avoid a `;` (it'll get hoisted to the top anyway) and squash the function down to one statement (combine two statements into one inside the ternary statement condition) to drop the `{}`*

**Note**: I'm not sure if it's cheating, but this has to be run from a console window of a browser already pointing at `http://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=1&sort=featured`. It relies on the fact that **jQuery** and the appropriate paging links are available on the page itself. Also, it only appears to work in **Firefox** and not in IE or Chrome.

**Output** (at time of posting):

```
38150 (in an alert dialog)
```

**Exploded/commented**:

```js
function f()
    //concat all the bounty labels to t (they take the format "+50")
    //happens to be elements with title attribute containing word 'an'
    (t+=$("[title~=an]").text(),
    //find the "next" (has rel=next attribute) button
    u = $("[rel*=x]")[0])       
        ?
        //if there is a next button, load it, and then recurse f again
        $("html").load(u.href,f)
        :
        //else eval the 0+a+b+...+z tally and alert the result
        alert(eval(t))
//kick off the initial scrape (and simultaneously init the total tally)
f(t=0)
```

Comment: `s=" #mainbar";d=$(s);t="";function a(){d.find(".bounty-indicator").each(function(){t+=this.innerHTML});(u=d.find("[rel=next]")[0])?d.load(u.href+s,a):alert(eval(t))}a();` 169 - used Google Closure Compiler.

Comment: Sneaky choice of language and context to bypass a lot of the required characters! (Such as "http://stackoverflow.com/") I like it!

Comment: I think you should mention that it is done using jQuery plugin. which I think it should be.. :)

Comment: Chrome throws a syntax error. Opening a function body with a `(` paren, does that really work?

Comment: @Mr_Green - I already noted that, but I've bolded it to draw more attention...

Comment: @thejh - Works fine in Firefox, but you're right it doesn't seem to work in Chrome or IE (I've made a note). Obviously different implementations accept different things and Firefox must allow single statement function bodies in the same way that you can drop the `{}`s in similar `if` statements. My function now contains a single ternary statement: `function f()a?b:c;`, where `a` happens to be a multi-part "statement" contained by `()`.

Comment: I'd +1 if the browser took me to the right page before executing.

Comment: @primo - :) I don't begrudge you that... like I said in my own answer, it's a bit of a cheat. And I'm happy for it not to "win" as it certainly wouldn't be anywhere near the best score if it did include 50 odd extra characters of url. But I'll leave that to OP to judge.

Answer (score 21):

### Python - <del>232</del>, <del>231</del>, <del>195</del>, <del>183</del>, <del>176</del>, 174

Parses the HTML from https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured using regular expressions.

The upper bound of `range` in the `for` loop *must* be `number of pages + 1` or else the code will raise `HTTPError` because of 404s. Default number of results per-page is 15, which is what the code uses (omitting `?pagesize=50` saves on characters and is just as effective).

Thanks to **@Gabe** for the tip on reducing char count even further.

**Golfed**:

```python
import requests,re;print sum(sum(map(int,re.findall(r"<.*>\+(\d+)<.*>",requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured&page=%u"%i).text)))for i in range(1,33))
```

**Output** (at time of posting):

```
37700
```

**Un-golfed**:

Here's a somewhat un-golfed version that should be a bit easier to read and understand.

```python
import requests, re

print sum(
          sum(
              map( int,
                   re.findall( r"<.*>\+(\d+)<.*>",
                               requests.get( "https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured&page=%u" % i).text
                   )
              )
          ) for i in range( 1, 33 )
      )
```

Comment: You can get rid of the explicit `for` loop and get it down to 176: `import urllib,re;print sum(sum(map(int,re.findall(r"<.*>\+(\d+)<.*>",urllib.urlopen("http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured&page=%u"%i).read())))for i in range(1,33))`

Comment: having a hardcoded upper bound makes it a little difficult to test

Comment: [oh god](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/732016)

Comment: @WChargin, what?

Comment: It really isn't a good idea to parse HTML with regular expressions because it not guaranteed to work. More on that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: @Richard Yeah, but this is *code golf*, so brevity trumps whether it's a "good idea".  I mean, in Real Life it's also not a good idea to write horrendous one-liners with no whitespace...

Comment: @Richard Parsing html and extracting from html are pretty different tasks. Since a website is not a stable API, nothing is *guaranteed* to work for this kind of extraction. Though Tony's code is a bit overgolfed, so it'd fail if there is *any* tag containing a `+` followed by a number. For example a question title could fit that format.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Thanks for the clarification. I figured it might be out of the scope of the question, but thought I would share.

Comment: 174 by request of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/25232/10740

Answer (score 18):

## Rebol - <s>164</s> <s>133</s> 130 (139 with 404 check)

Parses the html using the `parse` sub-language of Rebol. Checks the first 98 pages. I realised I have the same constraint as the python solution - too many repeats hit 404 errors and stop the execution.
Thanks to @rgchris for many improvements! Updated to check up to 98 pages.

`s: 0 repeat n 99[parse read join http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured&page= n[15[thru{>+}copy x to{<}(s: s + do x)]]]s`

With error checking for 404s (139):

`s: 0 repeat n 99[attempt[parse read join http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured&page= n[15[thru{>+}copy x to{<}(s: s + do x)]]]]s`

**Test**

```
>> s: 0 repeat n 20[parse read join http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured&page= n[15[thru{>+}copy x to{<}(s: s + do x)]]]s
== 23600

>> s: 0 repeat n 99[attempt[parse read join http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured&page= n[15[thru{>+}copy x to{<}(s: s + do x)]]]]s
Script: none Version: none Date: none
== 36050
```

**Explanation**

Rebol ignores whitespace, hence you can put it all on one line like that if you choose.  PARSE takes two inputs, and the first argument *(`read join ...`)* is fairly self-explanatory.   But here are some comments on the parse dialect instructions, in a more traditional indentation:

```
s: 0
repeat n 99 [
    parse read join http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured&page= n [
        ;-- match the enclosed pattern 15 times (the rule will fail politely when there are less entries)
        15 [
            ;-- seek the match position up THRU (and including) the string >+
            thru {>+}
            ;-- copy contents at the current position up TO (but not including) <
            copy x to {<}
            ;-- (Basically, run some non-dialected Rebol if this match point is reached) the do is a bit dangerous as it runs the string as code
            (s: s + do x)
        ]
    ]
]
;-- evaluator returns last value, we want the value in S
;-- (not the result of PARSE, that's a boolean on whether the end of input was reached)
s
```

Comment: Nice...I added an oridinary formatted version with some comments, hope you don't mind! It's always great to see how well Rebol nails so many problems with such literacy *(all in a [half-meg cross-platform Apache-licensed executable](http://rebolsource.net/)* but that makes things like REFORM stick out like a sore thumb  Every other bit makes sense but I still look at that word and go "REduce and FORM being turned into REFORM" is just *ugly*.  Obsessing over it is very [Hawthorne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Birth-Mark).  Oh, and you could change SOME to ANY and shave off a char! :-)

Comment: Oops, should be 133.

Comment: Note: You need to loop to a higher `n` value... there's currently 28 pages of bounties (for page size 15). Won't impact your char count though.

Comment: Thanks Alconja. Easy to go up to 98 pages before adding any more chars to the solution. I'll have to re-run the test from home tonight

Answer (score 11):

## Ruby, 260

```
require'open-uri'
require'zlib'
i=b=0
d=''
until /"has_more":f/=~d
i+=1
d=Zlib::GzipReader.new(open("http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/featured?site=stackoverflow&page=#{i}&pagesize=100")).read
b+=d.scan(/"bounty_amount":(\d+)/).map{|x|x[0].to_i}.reduce :+
end
p b
```

Uses the Stack Exchange API.

Output (as of time of original post):

```
37200
```

I'm not counting the `&pagesize=100` in the character count, because it works without it, but I just added that for convenience while testing. If you remove that, it does the same thing (except it eats more quota and takes slightly longer).

Comment: Nice, I only got it to 275 in Python

Comment: eats more quota??? You were supposed to use the SO and SO only.

Comment: @JanDvorak ??? I meant API quota.

Comment: The `require`s can be replaced with the `-r` command line flag.

Answer (score 8):

## Rebmu - <s>108</s>107

```
rtN99[parseRDrj[http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured&page=N][15[thru{>+}copyXto{<}(a+JdoX)]]]j
```

**Test**
(at 19:05 AEST)

```
>> rebmu [rtN99[parseRDrj[http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured&page=N][15[thru{>+}copyXto{<}(a+JdoX)]]]j]
Script: none Version: none Date: none
== 79200
```

[Rebmu](https://github.com/hostilefork/rebmu/tree/2965e013aa6e0573caa326780d97522a425103f0) looks rather cryptic, but it is quite readable once you get the hang of it. Let's start by unmushing it and laying it out properly.

```
rt n 99 [
    parse rd rj [
        http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured&page= n
    ][
        15 [
            thru {>+}
            copy x to {<}
            (a+ j do x)
        ]
    ]
]
j
```

Rebmu is a dialect of Rebol so you can see the similarities in the solution.  Rebmu can't reduce the size of every statement yet, but it is an evolving language. Thanks again to @rgchris for the improvements to my first attempt.

Comment: `ti` (to integer!) would be safer than `do` in Rebmu with no change in code length.

Answer (score 6):

## Ruby - 197

Short version:

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
s=0
(1..33).each{|p|Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=#{p}&sort=featured")).css('.bounty-indicator').each{|b|s+=b.content.to_i}}
p s
```

Human friendly version:

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
s=0
(1..33).each do |p|
    Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=#{p}&sort=featured")).css('.bounty-indicator').each do |b|
        s += b.content.to_i
    end
end
puts s
```

And answer - `39700`

## Ruby with script parameters - 139

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
s=0
(1..33).each{|p|Nokogiri::HTML(open(ARGV[0]+p.to_s)).css(ARGV[1]).each{|b|s+=b.content.to_i}}
p s
```

To run this from bash just type

```
ruby code_golf_stack_overflow2.rb http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured\&page= .bounty-indicator
```

Comment: The `require`s can be replaced with the `-r` command line flag.

Answer (score 6):

### PHP, <s>134</s>, <s>131</s>, 127

`while($q=array_sum(preg_filter('#.*>\+#',0,file("http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured&page=".++$n))))$s+=$q;echo$s;`

Will loop through **all** pages, `pagesize` is not set to save bytes so more `GET`s.

Very Very Dirty, but... taking advantage of `PHP`'s "flaws" !

- no space after `echo`
- `while` stops at assignment
- output after `RegEx` replace is a string starting with the bounty amount
- `array_sum()` adds up strings
- `$n` and `$s` are initialized, but starting from nothing is equiv. as starting from zero
- etc...

Answer (score 6):

### PHP - 121 bytes

```
<?for(;preg_filter('/>\+(\d+)/e','$t+=\1',@file('http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured&page='.++$n)););echo$t;
```

Using a regex 'eval' modifier, to avoid using `array_sum` or similar. Seems to be the shortest solution among valid entries.

Comment: the `e` modifier has been deprecated as of PHP 5.5, but it is still useful for golfing nonetheless.

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript - <del>129</del> <del>119</del> <del>110</del> 107 characters

### EDIT: INVALID ANSWER! This only handles the "Top featured  questions", which only has a fraction of them. Alconja's answer is more valid.

```
s="#mainbar";t="";eval("$(s).find('.bounty-indicator').each(function(){t+=this.innerHTML});alert(eval(t))")
```

Execute on https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured in a console window. Based on the solution by Alconja.

Golfed it a bit more by removing unneeded whitespaces.

Used eval to remove the function call, clearing another 9 characters.

cleared out some more unneeded whitespace.

Answer (score 5):

**Bash 206**

optimizations possible, too lazy

```
s=0;for i in `seq 1 11`;do for j in `wget -q -O - "http://stackoverflow.com/questions?pagesize=50&sort=featured&page=$i" | grep -o -E "bounty worth [0-9]*" | grep -o -E "[0-9]*"`;do s=$(($s+$j));done;done;echo $s
```

result:

```
39450
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but this looks like it could be *very* short with some quality optimizations.

Comment: `seq 1 11` can be reduced to `seq 11`.

Comment: You should be able to get rid of the spaces around pipes to save four chars, and surely those two greps can be merged into one (did you mean "[0-9]+"?).

Comment: Also "grep -o -E" => "egrep -o".

Comment: And you can change: "egrep -o '[0-9]+'" => "cut -d' ' -f3" :)

Answer (score 3):

## Java, 540 chars

***Warning: the number of active bounties is ~470. This code will access a page on stackoverflow that many times. It may get you in trouble with them for making so many data requests.***

```
import java.io.*;import java.net.*;public class B{public static void main(String[]A){String u="http://stackoverflow.com/questions",d;Long i,s=i=0L,n=i.parseLong(o(u).replaceAll("^.*b.>(\\d+).*$","$1"));while(i++<n){d=o(u+"?pagesize=1&sort=featured&page="+n).replaceAll("^.*ion.>.(\\d+).*$","$1");s+=d.matches(".*\\D.*")?0:n.parseLong(d);}System.out.print(s);}static String o(String s){String d="";try{BufferedReader r=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(s).openStream()));while((s=r.readLine())!=null)d+=s;}finally{return d;}}}
```

My output was `23400`, but when I ran @TonyH's code, I got `37550`. Bad news.

Pretty code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class StackOverflowBounty {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String u = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions", d;
        Long i, s = i = 0L, n = i.parseLong(o(u).replaceAll("^.*b.>(\\d+).*$", "$1"));
        while (i++ < n) {
            d = o(u + "?pagesize=1&sort=featured&page=" + n).replaceAll("^.*ion.>.(\\d+).*$", "$1");
            s += d.matches(".*\\D.*") ? 0 : n.parseLong(d);
        }
        System.out.print(s);
    }

    static String o(String s) {
        String d = "";
        try {
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(s).openStream()));
            while ((s = r.readLine()) != null) {
                d += s;
            }
        } finally {
            return d;
        }
    }
}
```

The way this works is simple. It reads from the url `http://stackoverflow.com/questions"` to determine the number of questions that have bounties (note: if the number increases, the program fails, but if it drops, it works fine). It searches for this number using the regex: `b.>(\\d+)`. This has worked in all tests to date, but if someone asked a question that matches that regex, this might not work.

Then, we open the url `http://stackoverflow.com/questions?pagesize=1&sort=featured&page=` + `current question #`. In other words, we open a new page for each featured question, and force the number of questions to be only `1`, so we will get them all. The reputation part will always match `ion.>.(\\d+)`, so I use that to find it. I split the operation into two parts so that I could cheaply check if the number of questions reduced (ie the string returned is not an integer).

Then, we sum up all the reputation and print it.

It took about 3 minutes and 20 seconds to run on my machine.

---

Does anyone know why it isn't printing the right number?

Comment: pagesize=100 gives the large number. I think something weird is happening because you're passing pagesize=1. In my answer, if i didn't specify 'pagesize', the result was close to your number.

Comment: @malik Yeah I realized that I "misread" your comment, so I deleted mine :-). pagesize=100 acts as if pagesize=50. Did you mean that you ran my code with pagesize=100?

Answer (score 2):

### C# - 407

```
class B{void Main(string[] a){var o=0;for(int i=1;i<11;i++){var r=((System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(string.Format(a[0]+"&page={0}",i)))).GetResponse();if(r.ContentLength>0){using(var s=new StreamReader(r.GetResponseStream()))foreach(Match m in Regex.Matches(s.ReadToEnd(),"bounty worth (.+?) "))o+=int.Parse(m.Value.Substring(m.Value.IndexOf('h')+2));}}Console.Write(o);}}
```

Using Stackoverflow.com. Same as below, except no Gzip decompressing and different regex.

**Test**

```
> prog.exe http://stackoverflow.com/questions?pagesize=50&sort=featured
38150
```

Weirdly, getting a different value than below.

---

### C# - 496

This uses api.stackexchange which is gzipped and json.

```
using System.IO.Compression;class B{void Main(string[] a){var o=0;for(int i=1;i<11;i++){var r=((System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(string.Format(a[0]+"&page={0}",i)))).GetResponse();if(r.ContentLength>0)using(var s=new StreamReader(new GZipStream(r.GetResponseStream(),CompressionMode.Decompress)))foreach(Match m in Regex.Matches(s.ReadToEnd(),@"bounty_amount"":(.+?),"))o+=int.Parse(m.Value.Substring(m.Value.IndexOf(':')+1).Replace(",",""));}Console.Write(o);}}
```

**Unminified:**

```
using System.IO.Compression;

class B
{
    void Main(string[] a)
    {
        var o = 0;
        for (int i=1; i<11; i++) {
            var w = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(string.Format(a[0]+"&page={0}",i)));
            if(w.GetResponse().ContentLength > 0)
                using(var s = new StreamReader(new GZipStream(w.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(),CompressionMode.Decompress)))
                    foreach(Match m in Regex.Matches(s.ReadToEnd(), @"bounty_amount"":(.+?),"))
                        o += int.Parse(m.Value.Substring(m.Value.IndexOf(':')+1).Replace(",", ""));
        }
        Console.Write(o);
    }
}
```

**Test**

Default pagesize:

```
> prog.exe http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/featured?site=stackoverflow
25300
```

Pagesize=100:

```
> prog.exe "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/featured?site=stackoverflow&pagesize=100"
37400
```

Answer (score 2):

## jQuery 191

```js
i=0;function f(p){$.get('//api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/featured?site=stackoverflow&page='+p,function(d){for(x in d.items)i+=d.items[x].bounty_amount;d.has_more?f(p+1):alert(i)})};f(1)
```

It works from anywhere in stackexchange(and many other sites), no need to be in a specific page as in @Alconja/@NateKerkhofs answers

Comment: jQuery's a library, not a language. Not sure if it's valid or not...

Comment: @br1ckb0t take it as javascript if you like. jQuery is already on stackexchange sites anyways, I was just being explicit about the `$`

Comment: Yep, that makes sense! Nice code.

Answer (score 2):

### PHP - 139

**Golfed:**

```
<?php
$a=file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured');preg_match_all('/n">\+([0-9]+)<\/div>/',$a,$r);echo array_sum($r[1]);
```

**Ungolfed - 147**

Simple `file_get_contents` / `preg_match` / `array_sum`

```
<?php
$a = file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured');
preg_match_all('/n">\+([0-9]+)<\/div>/', $a, $r);
echo array_sum($r[1]);
```

**Test:**

> php run.php
>
> 10250

Answer (score 2):

## Python (174 characters):

Expanding on the python answer above (don't have enough karma to comment):

```
import requests,re;print sum(sum(map(int,re.findall(r"<.*>\+(\d+)<.*>",requests.get("http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured&page=%u"%i).text)))for i in range(1,33))
```

Requests in lieu of urllib cuts down on 2 chars.

Answer (score 2):

## Bash 174

Based on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/25180/7664:

```
s=0;for i in {1..11};do for j in `wget -qO- "stackoverflow.com/questions?pagesize=50&sort=featured&page=$i"|cut -d' ' -f18|egrep '^[0-9]+$'`;do s=$(($s+$j));done;done;echo $s
```

Comment: You can get rid of the `pagesize=50&` and just loop more (I think the default page size if 15).

Comment: @Alconja Hmm, right, so I could get this down to 162... but only with the downside of more request spam to the server.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby (176 chars):

Following Tony H.'s example of using hard-coded page numbers, here's what I got:

```
require'open-uri';b=0;(1..29).each{|i|d=open("http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured&page=#{i}").read;b+=d.scan(/<.*>\+(\d+)<.*>/).map{|x|x[0].to_i}.reduce 0,:+};p b
```

gave me 35300 at the time of writing.